# XCode test Distribution ipa in device

Tags: xcode, testing, device, adhoc

I have a little problem and I am wondering if this is possible. I have just finished updating an app with push notification for a client. I don't have a hold of the server side so I tested the push by modifying the app id and just make it as my own temporarily, created the necessary certificates and provisioning profiles and then tested it using PushMeBaby app. All works fine without problems.

And now, the client wants to publish it and he gave me the distribution certificate and provisioning profile for distribution. I am not a member of his team but I somehow find a way to build it using the command line.

Now comes my problem, I wanted to test it first on my device to check if the push notification works. The server is already setup since it is already existing in the store. I know for sure that the push will work, but somehow I really feel the need to test it first on my device. I tried to request him to use testflight for testing but he said he doesn't know how to do it. I tried to present myself to do it but he doesn't allow it because the original developer made some anomalies with his account, so as much as possible, he won't give it to me saying there must be other way to test it myself.

And so I asked, is there any way to test it with just the distribution certificate and provisioning profile provided? If not, what would be the best alternative to do it, considering having the client do a very minimal and easy stuff on his side, if any.

Hoping for someone to actually give a hand or a hint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I understand your need to test before publishing, but I guess if you're extremely sure it will work then just release it. If there a too big problems remove the notification feature temporarily and upload another build (so to go back to the current version). This is what I would recommend.

Comment: I ended up convincing the client to take a peek at his account and somehow managed to use testflight. Thanks for your comment. :D